# Unable to access sub-folders in flask

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, glob

I am using below code to access sub-folders inside a folder named 'dataset' in VSCode, however, I am getting an empty list for **dataset** in the output and hence, unable to get json and image files stored inside that folder. Same code is working in Google Colab.

Code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Dataset path"""
    dataset_path = "vehicle images/dataset"
    dataset = glob(os.path.join(dataset_path, "*"))
    
    for data in dataset:
        image_path = glob(os.path.join(data, "*.jpg"))
        json_file  = glob(os.path.join(data, "*.json"))
```

File Structure in VSCode:
[image: flask folder structure]

File Structure in Google Colab:
[image: google colab]
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used space in folder name. So it can be solvable by two method either change the `vehicle images` folder to `vehicle_images` or use row string like

`dataset_path = r"vehicle images/dataset"`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have changed the folder name to vehicles and dataset_path now looks like `dataset_path = "vehicles/dataset"` however, it still returns an empty set like : `(venv) (base) mac123:dataset abc$ python3 process_data.py` -> []

Comment: Since it is flask app you will need to provide absolute path of that `vehicles/dataset` directory.